# Autocomplete textview with adapter showing weird issue

Tags: android

**JSON**

```
[{"MemberId":"MI001","MemberName":"Member 1"},
{"MemberId":"MI002","MemberName":"Member 2"},
{"MemberId":"MI003","MemberName":"Member 3"}]
```

When I input `member` in my `AutoCompleteTextView`, it will show three of them.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

then when I input `member 2` it's showing the value of `member 2`

**Here is there problem**: when I empty my `AutoCompleteTextView` and input `member` again, it is only showing `member 2`

**Adapter**

```
public class Adapter_member extends ArrayAdapter<Model_member> implements Filterable{
    private ArrayList<Model_member> mData,filteredmember,mDataAll;


    public Adapter_member(Context context, ArrayList<Model_member> m_member) {
        super(context, 0, m_member);
        this.mData = m_member;
        this.mDataAll = m_member;
        filteredmember = new ArrayList<Model_member>();
    }
    @Override
    public Model_member getItem(int position) {
        return mData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_member_layout, parent, false);
        }
        TextView memberName =  convertView.findViewById(R.id.membername);
        TextView memberId   =  convertView.findViewById(R.id.memberid);

        Model_member people = mData.get(position);
        if (people != null) {
                memberId.setText(people.getMember_id());
                memberName.setText(people.getMember_name());
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return myFilter;
    }

   private Filter myFilter = new Filter() {

        @Override
        public CharSequence convertResultToString(Object resultValue)
        {
            String str = resultValue.toString();
            return str;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            Log.d("TA", constraint.toString());
            if (constraint != null) {
                filteredmember.clear();
                for (Model_member people : mDataAll) {
                    if (people.getMember_name().toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                        filteredmember.add(people);
                    }
                }
            }else{
                return new FilterResults();
            }
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = filteredmember;
            filterResults.count = filteredmember.size();
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            ArrayList<Model_member> filteredList = (ArrayList<Model_member>) results.values;
            if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                clear();
                for (Model_member people : filteredList) {
                    add(people);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

and here is my pojo.

```
public class Model_member {
    String member_id,member_name;

    public  Model_member(){

    }

    public String getMember_id() {
        return member_id;
    }

    public void setMember_id(String member_id) {
        this.member_id = member_id;
    }

    public String getMember_name() {
        return member_name;
    }

    public void setMember_name(String member_name) {
        this.member_name = member_name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getMember_id() + " - " +getMember_name();
    }
}
```

how i can fix my problem ? sorry if i keep asking in Stackoverflow.

Comment: This happens when you don't clone your arraylist before replacing, you have to hold the original list before changing it.

Comment: Where are `clear()` and `add()` methods. The error must be in them.

Comment: It's obviously because not understanding `ArrayAdapter<T>` class ... use `BaseAdapter` instead ... first rule of extending `ArrayAdapter` is: **do not store own List/Array/Other collection inside ArrayAdapter implementation - ArrayAdapter does it already**

Comment: use some generic `Filterable` adapter like in this example: http://pastebin.com/07mBMT0t - do not try to reinvent the wheel with playing with custom `ArrayAdapter` / `BaseAdapter` etc

Comment: @pskink hey, i fix my problem. thanks to you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fix my problem. Thanks to downvote. I'm following @pskink way, using his MatchableArrayAdapter . Here is my new adapter

```
public class Adapter_member extends MatchableArrayAdapter<Model_member>{
    ArrayList<Model_member> m_member;

    public Adapter_member(Context context, int resource,   ArrayList<Model_member> m_member) {
        super(context, resource , m_member);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBind(Model_member item, View itemView, int position) {
        TextView text1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.memberid);
        TextView text2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.membername);

        text1.setText(item.getMember_id());
        text2.setText(item.getMember_name());
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean matches(Model_member value, CharSequence prefix, CharSequence lowerCasePrefix) {
        return value.getMember_name().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCasePrefix);
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't need `m_member` field

Comment: @pskink in constructor?

Comment: ArrayList<Model_member> m_member - you don't need this field

Comment: @pskink ohhh. ok, i delete it and it is still working. thanks again. i think your `MatchableArrayAdapter ` will help me later

Comment: sure it will, in most cases the code is simplified to one / two methods